# why arrays are initialized to default values but not arraylist in java?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

The implementation of `ArrayList` uses `Array` under the hood. However, `Arrays` are intialized to default values `(0 or null)` but `ArrayList` are just empty. why is this?

```
       int[] arr = new int[10];
       String[] arr1 = new String[11];
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1));
      List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);
      System.out.println(list);

      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
      [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
      []
```

This means every time I use, `ArrayList`, I need to fill stuff in;
I was trying the below part in my code and it was throwing `NoSuchElementException` and then I realized that it is not defaulted, where as `Arrays` do

```
if (list.get(i)==null){
         list.add(i,x);
  else:
        list.add(i,list.get(i)+x)
```

EDIT:

```
even List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);
prints [] although I initialized the size;
```

Comment: Regarding your edit: You did not set the size to 10.  You set the capacity to 10.  The size is 0 until you add an element to it.

Comment: *This means every time I use, ArrayList, I need to fill stuff in* ... Yes, you are not using it if you don't "fill stuff in".

Comment: You see no elements when you print list because its `toString()` method uses `size` to determine how many elements print, not capacity of array. When you create `ArrayList` with initial capacity `10` its size is still `0` because you didn't add any elements to it yet, even if array which stores your objects was initialized as new Object[10] which means it is filled with 10 nulls.

Comment: @user1988876 P.S. The "capacity" that you initialized the `ArrayList` with is just a hint, anyway.  If you specify the capacity as 10 you can still add 11 elements to it.  The results of your program should be the same no matter what capacity you specify; only the performance is affected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create an array, you specify the size. This is required because the size of arrays can't be changed after they are created. Something must go in each element of the array, then, and the most obvious thing to put is `0` or `null`.

On the other hand, `ArrayList`s are designed to be able to be resized. So you shouldn't have to specify the size when you create them. If the starting size is more then zero, it would have to initialize all those elements, and it's easier not to. So the starting size is zero.

Comment: What you initialized is the capacity, not the size. The array list makes room for 10 elements, but that doesn't mean it has 10 elements.

Answer (score 12):

When constructing an array, the number is the *actual* size of the array (and you can't change it later). The number in the `ArrayList` constructor is the initial *capacity* (space reserved for elements) but the *size* is zero. The size of an `ArrayList` can change after it is constructed.

Comment: but it can still default its value to zero or null. how does the dynamic nature of arraylist will affect what it contains

Comment: @user1988876 You are calling the `toString()` method of the arrayList. Since it's size is 0, the String built by toString is empty (check the source code). That's why you "see" nothing.

Comment: @GregHewgill Does this mean that even if you initialize the capacity at 10, you can add 20 elements nonetheless? (for an arraylist)

Comment: @Xbit Yes. The 10 is only the initial capacity. It can increase afterwards.

Comment: @Xbit specifying the initial capacity does not affect its behaviour at all, only its performance

Answer (score 4):

You could do it like this:

```
List<Integer> items = Arrays.asList(new Integer[10]);
```

And you would get a list with 10 null elements.

Similarly,

```
Integer[] numbers = new Integer[10];
Arrays.fill(numbers,0);
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(numbers);
```

And you get a list with 10 elements initialised to 0;

Answer (score 4):

The reason of `null` and `0` is difference between primitive and `Object` types. Their default values are `null` and `0`(only `false` for boolean) correspondingly. 
See  [The Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

`ArrayList` is not physically  empty after creating. It has initial capacity, but it shows his size `0` even you initialized it exactly.Because Collection `size()` has logical meaning, not phisical.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);
```

Also you can fill new Collection (List) with the following static method

```
Collections.fill(list, 0) // int 0 is auto-boxed to `Integers` 0
```

Comment: NOTE: fill() does not work directly after initializing since the list size = 0. See nCopies() answer for this case.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are looking for [`Collections.nCopies`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies%28int,%20T%29):

```java
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(10, 0));
```

Answer (score 3):

As an ArrayList doesn't initially contain any elements, it can't default the value of those elements to null or any other value.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the `ArrayList` collection is to be virtually as fast as an array, without any waste (= preallocation) of space. Therefore, it is initialized to `size 0` (i.e., empty), as opposed to having multiple `null` values (although practically speaking the underlying array is constructed to the specified capacity).

Having said that, note also that an `ArrayList` will store objects and not primitives (e.g., `String` objects and not `char` or `int` primitives).

Answer (score 1):

This is because there is no constructor in `ArrayList` which could create an instance of certain size. `Collections.nCopies(int n, T o)` allows to create a List with predefined size and initialize it with any values. BTW internally it uses `CopiesList` class which has `CopiesList(int n, E e)` constructor